# Datalist not working in bootstrap modal-dialog box pop on chrome

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome

i'm using jquery for generate data and append to html #id.but datalist working fine in firefox ,issue in chrome
html code :

```
    <td>
    <input type="type" class="form-control products" id="product_onchange"  name="onchangeValue" list="listValue"/>
    <datalist id="listValue">       
    </datalist>
    </td>
```

script code :

```
    var update_product_dropdown = function (elm) {
    $.ajax({
    url:"api/v1/skuproducts?client_id="+$(elm).val(),
    method:"GET"
    }).done(function(data) {
    var optList = "";
    optList += "<option value=''>Select the Product</option>";
    for(var d in data) {
    optList +="<option value='["+data[d].product_code+"]-"+data[d].product_name+"'>                   ["+data[d].product_code+"]-"+data[d].product_name+"</option>";
    }
    $("#listValue").html(optList);
    })
    .fail(function() {
    console.log( "error" );
    });
    }
```

Comment: Can you please get a working http://fiddle.net for us to use?

Answer (score 1):

This is happens because your modal z-index(css) bigger that z-index of your datalist, you need increase z-index of datalist by adding next lines to your css file:

```
   datalist{
       z-index: 1000;
   }
```

also i found this problem for firefox.

Comment: i tried but not working on chrome ur idea only working firefox
datalist{
   z-index:1500 !important;
   display:block !important;
}

Comment: could you provide link to your site, probably some other component cover data list, and you should check this component z-index

Comment: what i found, that sometimes datalist is filed in chrome(and you can see arrow in right part of input field in datalist and if you click on this arrow you will see the data list options menu), but popup dont fire automatically while you are typeing, could you check?this is little bit other problem, could you check exactly which one problem do you have?

Comment: Now my code is working without any changes.i think chrome version is problem.